# pygame Rect group isn't moving

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

I have a problem. In my pygame code, There is a group of villians, which are always moving towards the hero. In this function I tried to update the x and y values of each rect of a villian with a certain amount of steps (-5), but the rects won't change from their initial stage on the screen. what's wrong with the function? Thank you.

```
def updateXY_villians():####################### not updating ################
    global lstVillainRect
    for villian in lstVillainRect:
        villian = villian.move(-5, 0)


def CreateVillainsRect(lstVillainXY_type):
    lstVillainRect = []
    for x, y, tiles in lstVillainXY_type:
        lstVillainRect.append(pygame.Rect(x, y, CUBE_WIDTH, CUBE_HEIGHT))
    return lstVillainRect

def makeListOfVillainXY_type():
    global lstVillainXY_type
    lstVillainXY_type = []
    lastI = 0
    for i in range(CHARACTER_START_PLACE_X + 100, SCREEN_WIDTH - 20, 200):
        type = random.randrange(0, 5)
        x = random.randrange(lastI, i)
        y = lst_villain_y[type]
        lstVillainXY_type.append((x, y, type))
        lastI = i
    for x, y, type in lstVillainXY_type:
        for restX, restY, restType in lstVillainXY_type:
            if abs(x - restX) < CUBE_WIDTH:
                lstVillainXY_type.remove((restX, restY, restType))
    return sorted(lstVillainXY_type)
```

Comment: Please include a [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your program.

Comment: Do you remember to redraw them? you have to draw them every time you move them

Comment: Nick they are images, with a get_rect() attrubiute and a list of their rects

Comment: @YairHaber They still need to be redrawn, pygame won't automatically update it's screen, show us more code, also, what is `villian`? does `villian.move` actually return a `villian` or does it return `None`

Comment: villian is a rect of one of the villians, i iterate throgh the list

Comment: how to redraw 'em?

Comment: added more functions so you could see whats lstVillianRect contains

Comment: @YairHaber You're creating a list of `Rect`s in `CreateVillainsRect`, and then you update these `Rect`s but then you never do anything with the returned list. In fact, **you don't even appear to be calling the `updateXY_villians()` function at all**

Comment: nick i have a main() function and as part as the moving of the villians function, i try to update their XY attrubiutes. the problem is the function isn't updating the list on the first place.

Comment: It's difficult to help you, because we can't run and test the code you've posted. Read the [mcve page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) thoroughly and then update your code example.

Answer (score 0):

In `updateXY_villians` you don't update the `villian` (the rect) in the list, but create a new rect and assign it to the name `villian`. The `villian` variable gets overriden in the next iteration and the last `villian` rect is lost.

```
for villian in lstVillainRect:
    villian = villian.move(-5, 0)
```

To update the rects in the list you need to call the `move_ip` method which moves the rect *in place* without creating a new rect.

```
for villian in lstVillainRect:
    villian.move_ip(-5, 0)
```

Comment: BTW, don't use global variables, since they make code harder to understand and maintain and rather pass the list to the function and return the updated list.